# Apache Tomcat 9.0 error in loading localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

Apache tomcat server perfectly starts from the console, but it generates error when I try to open the localhost page in my web browser.I am done with setting all the paths in Environment Variables and it was working fine but suddenly it started to generate this error

Here is a screenshot displaying the error

[image]

And this is the full error message-

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:338)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.<clinit>(CompositeELResolver.java:29)
org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<clinit>(ELContextImpl.java:86)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1617)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:750)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:950)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELResolver
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.<clinit>(CompositeELResolver.java:29)
org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<clinit>(ELContextImpl.java:86)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1617)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:750)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:950)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Please help me out,Thanks in advance**

Note:-This error comes when I try to open the localhost page on web browser.

**Update**

When I try to reload the browser window, the error message changes to as follows

[image]

**AND**

[image]

Tomcat lib directory

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360296/2540669) helpful

Comment: I have tried that before it didn't help me....

Comment: can you post the `tomcat lib directory` snapshot?

Comment: Done posting `tomcat lib directory` snapshot

Comment: Looks like tomcat is broken, try re-installing

Comment: I done this couple of times,but in vain !!

Comment: copy paste jdk/jre/lib/ext/tools.jar to tomcat/bin and from tomcat servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar to jdk/jre/lib/ext/ folder

Comment: The problem still remains....I have tried installing different versions of tomcat too